# bad performance while I load lots of images in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, optimization, ios6, uicollectionview

I have to display lots of images in UIcollectionView, may be greater than 200. Images are of big sizes. But there is serious performance issue out there. Scrolling became slow and sometimes it gets crashed . I dont know whats the best way to optimize in this kind of situation. 
I have custo cell which contains a UIImageView and I load image in method:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)CollectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PhotoCollectionCell *cell = [CollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 if(cell==nil){

        NSLog(@"cell is nil");
    }



    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
    ImagesDb *imageObj = [folderImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ImagesDataDb *imageData = imageObj.data;



    cell.cellImage.image = imageData.orignalImage;




    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];



        }

    return cell;


}
```

Comment: [cell viewWithTag:100] - What this method does?

Comment: What is the size of those image (dimensions)? and what is the bounds of the UIImageView?

Comment: who is ImagesDb? What is the size of ImagesDataDb and what is type of this object?

Comment: [cell viewWithTag:100]---it is label with tag as 100

Comment: who is ImagesDb? What is the size of ImagesDataDb and what is type of this object?---it is an nsmanagedObject . It contains image data

Comment: NSLog(@"size of myObject: %zd", malloc_size(imageData.orignalImage));---it returns 48

Comment: and the size of image is {1536, 2048}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you can do it's limit the size of the image which use in cell, becouse now you load full size image. The best way if you display images which size equal or smaller cell.

*according to the documentation:*

> In low-memory situations, image data may be purged from a UIImage object to free up memory on the system. This purging behavior affects only the image data stored internally by the UIImage object and not the object itself. When you attempt to draw an image whose data has been purged, the image object automatically reloads the data from its original file. This extra load step, however, may incur a small performance penalty.
>
> You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x
> 1024 in size. Besides the large amount of memory such an image would
> consume, you may run into problems when using the image as a texture
> in OpenGL ES or when drawing the image to a view or layer. This size
> restriction does not apply if you are performing code-based
> manipulations, such as resizing an image larger than 1024 x 1024
> pixels by drawing it to a bitmap-backed graphics context. In fact, you
> may need to resize an image in this manner (or break it into several
> smaller images) in order to draw it to one of your views.

Comment: documentation link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: simple collection view with images: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860

Comment: but I ahve one doubt. In my collectionview only 2/3 images are getting displayed at one time. So os should load the 2-3 images only. DOes that also create memory problem ?

Comment: also when I scroll, the cell gets reused and previous images gets out from memory, SO whY I am facing this issue ?

Comment: Also, I can always restrict the size of images but what would happen when I have 1000 images in a folder ?

Comment: If your images bigger than 1024 px, this can make the problem with memory if you try to add this image on screen because your image will be loaded into memory.

Comment: If you have a lot of images in a folder then this app should work fine because you use "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" and store only those images which shown on the screen

Comment: Yes. As anton said you need to control the image size while loading in collection view cell. Try auto release pool block while loading images that will handle the memory up to some instant.

Comment: one more thing I want to add. Is that issue with my NSmanagedObject, each time I load new images, coredataoject image property get accessed and that image data gets loaded into memory. So scrolling will load lots of objects and they remain in memory. is that the issue?

Comment: You may download your images in background thread, the best way use queue to limit the number of uploaded/downloaded images. 

After you download the image in background, you should not update the entire collection. Use reloadItemsAtIndexPaths: in main thread for update cell

Comment: Thanks Anton. For the time being,I have reduced the size of image and now its working better. Lets me take a dive into details later.I would surely get to this problem later and would bother you :). As of now this is my accepted answer. Thanks!